# Haskell-Custom data structure from an array

Tags: haskell

I need some advice on how to list only words from `Text` branches in this code I have programmed.

```
data Article = Text String
             | Section String [Article] deriving (Show)

myArticle :: Article
myArticle = Section "Document" [
                 Section "Introduction" [
                       Text "My intoduction",
                       Section "Notation" [Text "alpha beta gamma"]],
                 Section "Methods" [
                       Section "Functional Programming" [Text "FPR"],
                       Section "Logical Programming" [Text "LPR"]],
                 Section "Results" [Text "All is great"]]

tex :: Article -> [String]
tex (Text x) = [x]
tex (Section x (l:ls)) = tex l
```

I tried to call ls in the `tex` function, but it throws me an error. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [the `concatMap` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap). This will run the function you give it on each element of the input list, and concatenate all of the results together into a single list. Also, you don't need to use `:` to bind a list unless you actually want to break it into its head and tail (and in your case, you don't). So change the last line of your code to this:

```
tex (Section x ls) = concatMap tex ls
```

And then `tex myArticle` will be `["My intoduction","alpha beta gamma","FPR","LPR","All is great"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You pattern match with `(l:ls)`, which means it is a non-empty list, and you only work with `l`, so the first item, you "ignore" the rest of the `Article`s (which can be `Text`s and `Section`s).

You can match with any list, and then have to process that list by generating a list of `String`s for each subitem, and concatenating these, so:

```
tex :: Article -> [String]
tex (Text x) = [x]
tex (Section _ ls) = … ls
```